# I can write data but I can't read in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to firebase. I have a problem with firebase security rules. I can write data to the firebase database but I can't read the written data.
My database look like-

```
user|
    |_uid(auto-generated)
         |
         |_name:Bob
         |_score:100
         |_email:bob@gmail.com
```

My firebase database rule look like-

```
"user":{
       "$uid":{
              "uname":{

".read":"$uid=== auth.uid",
".write":"$uid=== auth.uid"
                    },
              "score":{
".read":"$uid=== auth.uid",
".write":false
                    },
              "email":{
".read":"$uid=== auth.uid",
".write":"$uid=== auth.uid"
                      }
}}
```

I have tested with simulator and everything(both read and write) goes fine. But can't read from my app although I logged in to an account.
When I set all read and write to true upper **$uid** node, all read write from my app OK too. But I want to allow read to authorized person only

I have already searched on stackoverflow, but there is no solution for this.

Sorry for my English writing skill.

Comment: "But can't read from my app" Please edit your question to include the [minimal complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using realtime database the best way to handle this is to create a `child authorized` and then save all authorized uid in this child and then set your rules as follows:`"rules":

```
 {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "root.child('authorized').hasChild(auth.uid)"
  }
}`
```

you can refer to this [project to see sample implementation](https://github.com/ggichure/Travelmantics/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/travelmantics/FirebaseUtil.java)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you used push() when creating the uid inside user node then the authid and uid are not the same. They have different values.MAKE SURE YOU USED THE SAME UID FROM

   ```
    firebaseauth.getinstance().getcurrentuser().getuid()
   ```
2. If you want to authorize people to only do something to only their data you can use the following set of Rules.

   ```
   {
   "rules": {
   "user": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
     }
    }
   }
   ```
3. The node you have is name but the level indicated on the rules is uname...

Comment: 1. Yeah, uid and authid are the same.   2.I can't read under **$uid** . If I set read and write under **users** it goes fine.